# Find that $k=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

An easy problem, but I'm really stuck!

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be such that $$f(x+y)=e^{y}f(x)+e^{x}f(y)+k, \: \: \: \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$
>   Find $k$.

Answer (score 5):

$f(a)=f(0+a)=e^af(0)+e^0f(a)+k=e^af(0)+f(a)+k\implies e^af(0)+k=0$.

So $k=-e^af(0)$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$, we conclude $f(0)=0$ and $k=0$.

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

$f(0)=f(0+0)=e^0f(0)+e^0f(0)+k=2 f(0)+k\implies f(0)=-k.$  $$f(1)=f(1+0)=e^0f(1)+e^1f(0)+k=f(1)-e k+k\implies k(1-e)=0\implies k=0.$$

Comment: I suggest you post a follow-up Q: What are the continuous non-zero solutions, if any, to $f(x+y)=e^xf(y)+e^yf(x)$ ? So far,I  don't have an answer to this,

Answer (score 1):

First put $y=0$ in the relation to get
$$f(x)=f(x)+e^x f(0)+k$$
$$\implies k=-e^x f(0)$$
Next put both $x,y=0$
$$f(0)=2f(0)+k$$
$$\implies k=-f(0)$$
Putting $f(0)=-k$ in the previous equation,
$$k=e^x k$$
$$\implies x=0 \text { or } k=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$f^{'}(0+y)=e^{y}f^{'}(0)+e^{0}f(y)$

Now send the $f(y)$ term to the left side and multiply by $e^{-y}$ on both sides and integrate

$\int \frac{d(e^{-y}f(y))}{dy}dy=f^{'}(0)$

We get

$f(y)=f^{'}(0)ye^{y}$

Comment: F is not differentiate

Comment: Nor integrative